# Vue Scroll to top on pageload

Tags: javascript, vue.js, onbeforeunload, gridsome, js-scrollto

I'm currently using [Gridsome](https://gridsome.org/) in my [portfolio website](https://www.jobrodo.nl/). But when I'm on the bottom of a page on a mobile/tablet device that is longer then the page I'm navigating to, the page doesn't scroll to the top on Firefox. On Google Chrome it works fine.

I'm using the following code to scroll to the top of a page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

I have tried other solutions, but nothing seems to work. I don't want to use any jquery for this solution.

Comment: Are you using `vue-router`? If so you can take advantage of [scroll behavior](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html)

Comment: Are you sure your function fires? :)

Comment: I have two other functions where I scroll using JavaScript. One is scrolling to an ID and the other one is scrolling to top. Both are activated when an anchor is clicked.

Comment: In the eventslist on the html tag I can see this function. Also it doesn't throw any error.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I will take a look.

Comment: I don't know how, but I removed all the options and added some other stuff and now it's working fine... Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the following workaround, it is not the best result but it works for me.
Set the Y value to 1 or 2, Firefox seems to have a problem with the 0.

```
window.scrollTo(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `router` configuration like follows,

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [...],
  scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 }
  }
})
```

This will scroll to top on every `route` changes.

If you're not using `vue-router`, then add the following code inside the `mounted()` hook of your component.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}, 500);
```

Comment: Tried both options. Still doesn't solve the problem on Firefox. I applied the first one in `main.js` because the `vue-router` is used on that page. I had to change the code to `router.scrollBehavior = function(to, from , savedPosition) {}` because of an error, but still didn't work.

Comment: I don't know how, but I removed all the options and added some other stuff and now it's working fine... Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @JosBroers I'm running into the same issue with Firefox (even with scrollBehavior), and I would love to know how you fixed it!

Comment: @Sameh I didn't fix it. I added a fade in-out transition instead.